# How to have an iframe fill up the entire mobile web page after setting a negative top margin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I currently have an iframe filling up my whole page, but I want to give it a -40px top margin to make it look better.

The iframe is on a mobile page and it's 640px width and 100% height.

I tried to do: `height="calc(100% + 40px)"` but that did not seem to work, instead it gave me the width of a small bar at the top of my page.

But this is essentially what I want, I want to iframe to extent to the bottom of the page after bumping it up 40px.

Please someone save my day here haha!

code:

```
<html>
<meta content='width=350px, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />
<body style="margin: 0; height: 100%;">
<iframe style='margin-top: -40px;'
  src="URLHERE"
  frameborder="0"
  width="350px"
  height="100%">
</frameset>
</body>
</html>
</iframe>
```

Comment: add `margin-top:-40px;` to the iFrame CSS

Comment: Did you try what @APAD1 suggested above??

Comment: @APAD1 I did try this, but it did not change anything on the appearance of my iframe. edit: meaning it still not reached the bottom

Comment: It makes the iFrame move up 40px, post relevant code.

Comment: @APAD1 correct, it makes the entire frame move up 40 px, but then you are left with a white bar of 40px at the bottom, of the screen. My goal here to move it up 40px and still have the iframe reach the bottom of the screen.
Check my post edit for code :) Thanks!

Comment: @Snowlav you need to do what you initially tried - height: calc(100% + 40px) PLUS the top: -40px.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do what @APAD1 said PLUS adding the 40px to your 100% height.  However, this will move your scrollbar up 40px as well and could initially hide it.  Here is a full blown full width/height iframe solution, with -40px top:

```
html, body
{
   height: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
}
   .iframe
{
   position:absolute;
   top:-40px;
   left:0;
   width:100%;
   height:calc(100% + 40px);
}
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/60xs8bro/